# How to modify unsrtnat.bst

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I use `unsrtnat.bst` and I need to change the form:

> N.W. Ashcroft. Phys. Rev. Lett., 92, 187002. (2004).

to

> N.W. Ashcroft. Phys. Rev. Lett. **92**, 187002 (2004).

So I need to delete comma after journal title, delete dot after page and bold the volume.

Below I present `FUNCTION {format.date}`

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$
       pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
  month empty$
    'skip$
    { month
      " " * swap$ *
    }
  if$
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ %% added
  { "(" swap$ * ")" *}     %% added
if$
  extra.label *
}
```

and `FUNCTION {article}`

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      eid empty$
        { format.vol.num.pages output }
        { format.vol.num.eid output }
      if$
      new.block                        %% added
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      eid empty$
        { format.pages output }
        { format.eid output }
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.issn output
  format.doi output
  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is `biblatex` an option for you?

Answer (score 2):

To get a bold volume

1. You have to define a new function which prints the contents bold. This can be achieved by

   ```
   FUNCTION {bold}%%new func to print the argument with \textbf{}
   { duplicate$ empty$
       { pop$ "" }
       { "\textbf{" swap$ * "}" * }
     if$
   }
   ```
2. Modify the output of volume for article

   ```
   FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
   { volume bold%%changed field.or.null to bold
     number empty$
       'skip$
       { "\penalty0 (" number * ")" * *
         volume empty$
           { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
           'skip$
         if$
       }
     if$
     pages empty$
       'skip$
       { duplicate$ empty$
           { pop$ format.pages }
           { ":\penalty0 " * pages n.dashify * }
         if$
       }
     if$
   }
   ```
3. The comma after journal can be removed by the following ugly hack:

   a. Definining a new Function for journal
   b. do no punctation check

   ```
   FUNCTION {format.journal.article}
   { journal empty$
       'skip$
      { ". \emph{" journal * "}" * * }
     if$
   }

   FUNCTION {article}
   { output.bibitem
     format.authors "author" output.check
     author format.key output
     new.block
     format.title "title" output.check
     new.block
     crossref missing$
       { format.journal.article
         eid empty$
           { format.vol.num.pages output }
           { format.vol.num.eid output }
         if$
         format.date "year" output.check
       }
       { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
         eid empty$
           { format.pages output }
           { format.eid output }
         if$
       }
     if$
     format.issn output
     format.doi output
     format.url output
     new.block
     note output
     fin.entry
   }
   ```

---

After all this modification my example provides:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@article{PhysRevLett.92.187002,
  author = {Ashcroft, N. W.},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume = {92},
  issue = {18},
  pages = {187002},
  numpages = {4},
  year = {2004},
  publisher = {American Physical Society}
}
  title = {Hydrogen Dominant Metallic Alloys: High Temperature Superconductors?},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.92.187002},
  url = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.92.187002},
  month = {May},
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
```

That took some doing and I really recommend `biblatex`.

---

`biblatex` starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@article{PhysRevLett.92.187002,
  author = {Ashcroft, N. W.},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume = {92},
  pages = {187002},
  numpages = {4},
  year = {2004},
  publisher = {American Physical Society}
}
  title = {Hydrogen Dominant Metallic Alloys: High Temperature Superconductors?},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.92.187002},
  url = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.92.187002},
  month = {May},
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}
\begin{document}


\cite{PhysRevLett.92.187002}

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```